# How can I convert non-pdf urls into .pdf file?

Tags: python, pdf

Something like http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9A00EEDE1431E13BBC4850DFBF66838A649FDE

I can open it in chrome and download as a pdf file.
And I need to write it into a local .pdf file, but the url does not end in .pdf
How can I write it into local file?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? what have you tried?

Comment: I need the url ending in .pdf so that I can write it into a file, but I cannot find such a url.

Comment: You don't need the .url ending, you can just access the url and write the response to file.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
     outfile.write(data)
```